# „Заключний“ чи „кінцевий“?

Tags: переклад, росіянізм

Дуже часто чую вживання слова *заключний*, але в словниках немає такого слова.
В першому джерелі вказано, що слово "заключний" - вживане в українській мові слово; в другому і третьому вказано, що не рекомендовано вживати це слово, адже це калька з російської мови.

То чи можна його вживати чи ні?

[СУМ‑11: 3, 150](http://sum.in.ua/s/zakljuchnyj)

> **ЗАКЛЮЧНИЙ**, **‑а**, **‑е**. Який завершує що-небудь; останній, завершальний.
>
> *Завʼялов не вперше грав у виставі, яка йшла сьогодні, але ніколи ще він не проводив заключного акту з такою силою, як у цей вечір* (Любомир Дмитерко, Наречена, 1959, 131).
>
> ▲ **Заключний баланс** — складений на підставі інвентаризації усіх матеріальних цінностей і розрахункових взаємовідносин річний баланс, що є найповнішим і найточнішим відображенням фінансово-господарського стану підприємства.
>
> ♦ **Заключний акорд** див. [акорд](http://sum.in.ua/s/akord) 1.

[ОnlineСorrector: кінцевий, прикінцевий, підсумковий, остаточний і заключний](http://onlinecorrector.com.ua/%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%96%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9/)

> Замініть прикметник *заключний*, якщо мовиться про щось, на стилістично кращий варіант: *кінцевий*, *прикінцевий*; *підсумковий*; *остаточний*.
>
> **Не рекомендовано • рекомендовано:**
>
> - *заключне* слово • *прикінцеве* слово
> - *заключне* положення • *кінцеве* положення
> - *заключне* рішення • *остаточне* рішення
> - *заключний* контроль • *підсумковий* контроль

«[Як ми говоримо](http://yak-my-hovorymo.wikidot.com/zaklyuchnyj-kincevyj-prykincevyj-ostatochnyj)» [Бориса Антоненка-Давидовича](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%94%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87_%D0%91%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81_%D0%94%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87)

> #### Заключний, кінцевий, прикінцевий, остаточний
>
> Заключний, кінцевий, прикінцевий, остаточний
>   Дієслово *заключати* й похідний від нього прикметник *заключний*, а також іменник *заключення* нерідко доводиться чути з уст і бачити на письмі:
>
> > «Колгосп *заключив* договір на продаж городини»; «З досвіду минулого можна *заключити*, що до весни треба готуватися взимку»; «На *заключения* зльоту відбувся концерт»; «*Заключна* вистава театру пройшла з великим успіхом»; «У своєму *заключному* слові доповідач відповів на всі питання».
>
> Прикметник *заключний* попав навіть до наших словників, хоч дієслова *заключати* й віддієслівного іменника *заключения* там немає. Чому? Та тому, що дієслова *заключати* нема в українській мові, а прикметник *заключний* є не що інше, як калька з російського слова *заключительный*.
>
> Яка потреба в такому калькуванні? Чи нема відомих українських відповідників, що доводиться на певні поняття позичати слова з інших мов? Ні, такі відповідники є, ними широко користуються ті, що дбають за культуру своєї мови. Ось прикметник *кінцевий*:
>
> > «*Кінцеві* форми тієї еволюції». — А. Кримський; «Розмір додаткової оплати визначається залежно від *кінцевих* результатів роботи тваринників». — «Радянська Україна»);
>
> Є ще прикметник *прикінцевий*:
>
> > «У *прикінцевій* строфі висловлено основну думку твору». — «Історія української літератури»;
>
> В деяких випадках відповідником до російського прикметника заключительный є слово *остаточний*, наприклад:
>
> > *остаточний* баланс, *остаточна* цифра
> >
> > «Почисливши все звільна, він прочитав *остаточну* цифру без голосу». — І. Франко.
>
> З цих прикладів бачимо, що в наведених на початку фразах можна й треба було написати:
>
> > «Колгосп *уклав* договір»; «Можна зробити *висновок*»; «*На закінчення* (*наприкінці*, *наостанку*) зльоту»; «У *кінцевому* (*прикінцевому*) слові».

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В журналі "Культура слова" №82 за 2015 рік є пояснення щодо цього випадку.

> У сучасному професійному вжитку активні словосполучення заключний концерт, заключний акорд, заключна сцена, заключний тур, заключне слово, заключна частина, заключний баланс та ін. Проте цього прикметника не було в художніх творах української класичної літератури. Він є буквальним перекладом прикметника російської мови заключительный, пор.: заключительный концерт, заключительный аккорд, заключительная сцена, заключительное слово, заключительный баланс і т. д. В українській мові його значення виражає кілька прикметників: заключний концерт – підсумковий (завершальний) концерт; заключний акорд – останній акорд; 
>   заключна сцена – фінальна (остання) сцена; заключний тур – фінальний тур; заключне слово – прикінцеве (підсумкове) слово; заключна частина – фінальна (остання) частина; заключний баланс – остаточний (підсумковий) баланс.
>   Отже, замість заключний у словосполученнях залежно від їхнього значення потрібно вживати **завершальний,підсумковий, останній, фінальний, остаточний**.